# Reduce Legend font size, add percentage sign in ylabel and custom axes in R radar-plot?

Tags: r, radar-chart

I am looking for edits in the below code for:-

1. Reducing font size of legend
2. Percentage signs along caxislabels
3. Each axes has it's own labels

Code I am using currently:

```
# Library
library(fmsb)

data <- data.frame("A"=c(90,50,40) , "B"=c(10,20,30),"C"=c(20,30,90), "D"=c(10,20,30),"E"=c(10,30,30) )
rownames(data) <- c("X","Y","Z" )

# To use the fmsb package, I have to add 2 lines to the dataframe: the max and min of each variable to show on the plot!
data <- rbind(rep(0,10) , rep(100,10) , data)

# Color vector
colors_border=c( rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.9) , rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.9) )
colors_in=c( rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.4), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.4) , rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.4) )

# plot with default options:
radarchart( data  , axistype=1 , seg = 5,
    #custom polygon
    pcol=colors_border , pfcol=colors_in , plwd=1 , plty=1,
    #custom the grid
    cglcol="gray71", cglty=1, axislabcol="gray54", caxislabels=seq(100,0,-20), cglwd=0.8,
    #custom labels
    vlcex=0.8, calcex=0.7
    )

# Add a legend
legend(x=0.7, y=1.2, legend = rownames(data[-c(1,2),]), bty = "n", pch=20 , col=colors_in , text.col = "gray32", cex=1.2, pt.cex=3)
```

Output generated:

[image: output]

Desired output:

[image: desiredoutput]

Reason?:

Need it for my dissertation due in a week's time. Please if one of the three can't be solved in R, can an alternate software be suggested for Radar plots? 
Thanks!

Comment: This is not a `ggplot2` graphics. See vignette and help pages for the answer. You can find how to add % here, for example: https://rdrr.io/cran/fmsb/man/radarchart.html

Comment: This link can be useful too https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/143-spider-chart-with-saveral-individuals.html

Comment: @atsyplenkov I did them both  rdrr.io/cran/fmsb/man/radarchart.html doesn't talk about % and  r-graph-gallery.com/ is where I took the code from and modified it